# Listar postagens de amigos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Tenho um banco de dados com a seguinte estrutura:

**Tabela usuarios:**

```
usuario_id   Primária   int(11)
nome                    varchar(128)
nascimento              date
```

**Tabela amizades:**

```
id_amizade   Primária   int(11)
id_remenente            int(11)
id_destinatario         int(11)
data_envio              datetime
data_resposta           datetime
sao_amigos              int(11)
```

**Tabela posts:**

```
post_id    Primária     int(11)
id_autor                int(11)
texto                   longtext
data                    datetime
```

Preciso carregar postagens dos amigos do usuário, tentei usar `INNER JOIN` mas não sei utilizar corretamente...

Comment: Como você identifica se são amigos? Na tabela amizade tem um campo mas ele é int e não booleano.

Comment: Eu utilizo 0 ou 1

Comment: Qual a relação entre usuario e amizades? O `id_usuario`  é qual campo em amizades?

Comment: @Ricardo aparentemente, id destinatario e id remetente sao ids de usuarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem o significado dos campos nas tabelas você pode pegar assim:

```
select u.usuario_id as idUsuario,
       u.nome as nomeUsuario,
       a.id_remenente as idAmigo,
       a.sao_amigos as IndicadorDeAmigo,
       p.post_id as idDoPost

from usuario as u
inner join amizades as a on u.usuario_id = a.id_destinatario
inner join posts as p on a.id_remenente = p.id_autor
where u.usuario_id = 1
and a.sao_amigos = 1
```

Fiz o `join` de todas as tabelas considerando que você quer pegar os posts que um amigo envio para o usuário logado, então:

Todos os usuários `join` com amizades onde o usuário logado é o destinatário do post `u.usuario_id = a.id_destinatario`

Fazendo join com post onde o remetente da mensagem (amigo do usuário logado que o envio a mensagem) é o dono do post `a.id_remenente = p.id_autor`

Filtrando tudo do usuário logado `1` e que é amigo (`a.sao_amigos = 1`)

Aqui o [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3067d/1) com ele funcionando.

No Fiddle o Ricardo é o usuário logado, o Daniel e o Felipe mandaram posts para ele, mas somente o Daniel é amigo, logo somente o post do Daniel apareceu.

**ATUALIZANDO**

De acordo com o comentário, você pode fazer assim: ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3067d/4))

```
select *
 from posts
 where id_autor in 
   (select id_destinatario 
      from amizades
     where id_remenente = 1 
       and sao_amigos = 1)
union
select *
 from posts
 where id_autor in 
   (select id_remenente
      from amizades
     where id_destinatario  = 1 
       and sao_amigos = 1)
```

Pegar todos os post de um usuário que recebeu uma solicitação de amizade do usuário logado e confirmou **mais** todos os posts de um usuário que enviou uma solicitação para o usuário logado e o usuário aceitou.

Comment: Os posts não são enviados de um usuário para outro, devem ser listados apenas todos os posts dos usuários que são amigos do usuário logado.

Comment: Coloquei outro SQL na resposta, tem outro link para o fiddle também.

Comment: ok, está funcionando bem! mas se eu quizer pegar o nome do autor do post?

Comment: Opa, consegui! Obrigado!

Comment: E se eu quizer exibir também alguns posts do usuário logado qual alteração eu tenho que fazer?

Comment: Depende do que quer dizer com alguns, pêra pegar tudo do logado basta pegar idautor igual ao id do usuário logado, certo?